# Dojo : TypeError: dojo.byId(...).get is not a function

Tags: javascript, dojo

Dojo : TypeError: dojo.byId(...).get is not a function

Im having troubles getting a checkbox value using Dojo, i used dojo.byId('nodeID').get("value") but it doesn't work, the problem is that it work in another files, is my syntax wrong?
This is the code i tried in my function

```
dojo.provide('m.client.binding.bank.report_bg_client');
(function(/* Dojo */d, /* Dijit */dj, m) {

d.addOnLoad(function(){
        let cbxValue = **d.byId**('multi_beneficiaries').get("value");
        console.log(cbxValue);
});
```

Comment: Are you getting an error or are you getting a blank value ?

Comment: could you post the whole code ? function(/* Dojo */d, /* Dijit */dj, m) how did you load module here ?

Comment: No i'm not getting a blank value, but a TypeError error in my console

Comment: Hard to help with the current code provided, but by the looks of the error it cannot find the checkbox widget which  i) might not exist at the time of execution ii) Or the id does match the checkbox id.